# нужна помощь со скриптом Lua

Tags: разработка-игр, lua, love2d

мне нужно написать написать скрипт на Lua, когда игрок подходит близко к объекту, то у него появляется возможность нажать клавишу E, и когда он ее нажимает будет открываться панель, в это время(когда панель открыта) он не может двигаться пока снова не нажмет Е.
Как это можно сделать? Вот сам код ↓

```
local object = { x = 200, y = 200, width = 50, height = 50 }
local panelVisible = false

function love.load()
  love.window.setTitle("Интерактивный объект")
end

function love.update(dt)
  -- Проверка расстояния между игроком и объектом
  local distance = math.sqrt((player.x - object.x)^2 + (player.y - object.y)^2)

  -- Если игрок близко к объекту и нажимает клавишу E, открываем/закрываем панель
  if distance < 50 and love.keyboard.isDown("e") then
    panelVisible = not panelVisible
  end

  -- Если панель открыта, блокируем движение игрока
  if panelVisible then
    return
  end

  -- Обработка движения игрока (пример)
  if love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
    player.y = player.y - 100 * dt
  elseif love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
    player.y = player.y + 100 * dt
  elseif love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
    player.x = player.x - 100 * dt
  elseif love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
    player.x = player.x + 100 * dt
  end
end

function love.draw()
  -- Отрисовка объекта
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height)

  -- Отрисовка игрока
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)

  -- Отрисовка панели, если она видима
  if panelVisible then
    love.graphics.print("Панель открыта. Нажмите E, чтобы закрыть.", 10, 10)
  end
end
```